# Chrome extension : background and devtool_page communication

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

So I'm developping an extension for Chrome that reads **headers**.
Only the background.js has the ability to read those headers (from what I've understood, tell me if I'm wrong).

This extension is in **devtools** (F12), here is an extract from my manifest :

```
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest", "<all_urls>"
    ],
```

this devtool.html has a devtool.js that calls :

```
    chrome.devtools.panels.create('test', '/icon.png', '/panel.html', function(extensionPanel) {
        ...
    }
```

so that I have a panel.html (containing a panel.js), representing the interface.

---

**The question is** : How can I emit messages from the background.js to the panel.js ?

**What works so far** : The panel is visible in the devtools, my html and scripts from panel.html and panel.js are as expected. I know how to get the devtool's console (CTRL + SHIFT + "I" or "J" while focusing the devtools) in order to debug.

*Note* : Only the devtool.js and panel.js have their console.log() recorded in this console. I couldn't find where the background.js sends his console.log().

---

I've tested everything from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple , maybe I did them wrong. I can't find how to do this.

---

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: You can access the background console from `chrome://extensions`. Look for a link next to `inspect views`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem.

It's not the way it work : background.js is useless.
In panel.js, I can call

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
    function(request) {
```

which gives access to those headers informations :

```
        console.log(request.time);
        console.log(request.request.url);
        console.log(request.request.queryString[2]);
        console.log(request.response.status);
        console.log(request.response.headers[3]);
```

Comment: You were trying to mash together two different approaches: a DevTools extension, and `webRequest`. Background is not _useless_, you just never even tried to use `webRequest`, you switched completely to `chrome.devtools`

Comment: @Xan, Yes it's true I wasn't clear. In my case, the background.js wasn't needed. But I did tried to use the webRequest, and none of my atempts worked. I wanted, from the start, to use the webRequest in a devtools addon. I guess it's not how it should be done then.